# Is it possible to send messages to multiple queues using STOMP?

Tags: message-queue, activemq-classic, hornetq, stomp

I'm looking for a RabbitMQ replacement in a PHP project. Two options I am considering so far are Kestrel and Qpid (if we decide to stick with AMQP (which I would like to avoid)). In RabbitMQ, you can send a message to an exchange (destination), which decides which queues or topics (in JMS terms) the message should be delivered to. What stops me from choosing a STOMP server (ActiveMQ/Apollo or HornetQ) is that I can't find out whether it is possible in STOMP to SEND a message to a destination so that the message is delivered to a number of queues (in JMS terms)? The sender is not supposed to know which queues the message should be delivered to.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of something called [Composite Destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/composite-destinations.html) in ActiveMQ to do this with Stomp or the standard JMS client.  Stomp destinations are prefixed with the /queue/ string and then the name of the destination.  You also can use [Virtual Destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) in ActiveMQ.  And of course the Destination strings in ActiveMQ can support [wildcards](http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html).

Comment: If I understand correctly, wildcards may be used to subscribe to a group of queues, but not to send messages? And composite destinations require that all destinations be enumerated when sending the message, it goes against the idea of decoupling producers from consumers, it seems.

Comment: If you read the full page on composite destinations you will find a link to the broker side config that does what you want: http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html#VirtualDestinations-CompositeDestinations.  "Reading, its fundamental."

Comment: [ashamed, but persistent] Am I right that this may only be enabled in the server configuration files (hopefully, without restart)? Are STOMP selectors an adequate (and more flexible) replacement? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, these are server side configuration options.  ActiveMQ requires a restart, Apollo doesn't need to be restarted for many of its config options.

Answer (score 1):

In HornetQ, you can use [Diverts](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html_single/index.html#diverts) (exclusive and non-exclusive). The STOMP message will arrive in the original queue but will then be transparently diverted to the appropriate queues as configured in the hornetq-configuration.xml.

You can also apply filters with diverts so as to segregate messages into appropriate queues.

Comment: Sounds great, but I'm tempted to ask the same question: the diverts may only be enabled on the server side? And do STOMP selectors directly translate into filters?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same question myself and solved with below configuration in ActiveMQ XML.

```
<destinationInterceptors>
 <virtualDestinationInterceptor> 
  <virtualDestinations> 
   <compositeQueue name="MY.QUEUE">
    <forwardTo>
     <queue physicalName="FOO" /> 
     <queue physicalName="BAR" />
    </forwardTo>
   </compositeQueue>
  </virtualDestinations>
 </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
</destinationInterceptors>
```

Refer http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html